# Calculating jmp's from one segment to another in windows PE files

Tags: x86-64, reverse-engineering, portable-executable, ida

Assume I have a binary on my disk that I load into memory using VirtualAlloc and ReadFile.

If I want to follow a jmp instruction from one section to another, what do I need to add/subtract to get the destination address.

In other words, I want to know how IDA calculates the `loc_140845BB8` from `jmp     loc_140845BB8`

Example:

`.text:000000014005D74E                 jmp     loc_140845BB8`

Jumps to the section seg007

```
seg007:0000000140845BB8                                         ; seg007:0000000140845BC4↓j
seg007:0000000140845BB8                 and     rbx, r14
```

PE info (seg007 is the section named "")
[image: PE INFO]

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do. You loaded a PE from file without mapping its section. Then you have a `jmp` and... what? Its target is given by its immediate value (either relative or absolute). If you want to know in which section the target is (and at which offset), you can reason in terms of the distance between the (virtual) starting addresses of the sections. Or you can correctly map the PE. Please clarify what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

Segments are arbitary, it jumps where it jumps, without regard for segments.  Jump location is calculated as the signed 32-bit value following the 0xE9 JMP opcode, added to the the address of where the next instruction would be (i.e. the location of JMP + 5 bytes).

```py
def GetInsnLen(ea):
    insn = ida_ua.insn_t()
    return ida_ua.decode_insn(insn, ea)

def MakeSigned(number, size):
    number = number & (1<<size) - 1
    return number if number < 1<<size - 1 else - (1<<size) - (~number + 1)

def GetRawJumpTarget(ea):
    if ea is None:
        return None

    insnlen = GetInsnLen(ea)
    if not insnlen:
        return None
    result = MakeSigned(idc.get_wide_dword(ea + insnlen - 4), 32) + ea + insnlen
    if ida_ida.cvar.inf.min_ea <= result < ida_ida.cvar.inf.max_ea:
        return result
    return None
```